# Feature of showing the existing district on Map IN ArcGis JS

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I would like to ask that is there any method of features in ArcGIS can help me to show the current district that show on the map?

[image]

Like the picture above, ArcGIS have any features that can list down the districts that is currently on this map, For example, it able to list down: Kuala Lumpur, Shah Alam, PutraJaya, etc. And does not show out the district that currently doesn't appear on this view.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the layer that contains the districts with the view extent.

If the district are in a FeatureLayer on your map, then you just need to query the layer view, all your features are already local because you are actually seen it. Take a look at this example, it does exactly that to display some information of the features in a list [ArcGIS JS Examples - FeatureLayerView query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/featurelayerview-query/).
In the example, here is how he does the query,

```
layerView.queryFeatures({
    geometry: view.extent,
    returnGeometry: true,
    orderByFields: ["GEOID"]
})
.then(function (results) {
    graphics = results.features; // <- here are the features
    ...
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error("query failed: ", error);
});
```

Now if you don't have a FeatureLayer on the map with the districts, you will have to do a query to the service that contains that information. For this you can use `QueryTask` [ArcGIS JS API - QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-QueryTask.html).